# What is the Arduino compiler's version of `__unused` for function parameters?

Tags: c, compiler

When I first started with the Arduino environment I noticed that it had `File | Preferences | Compiler Warnings` set to `None`, so I set it to `All` - and there were many, many warnings in the supplied libraries! So I quickly set it to `None` again - until later.

Well, "later" is now, and I started going through the warnings to fix the code to quiet the compiler.

**Note that I don't want to *disable* any warnings** - I want to placate the compiler at each spot so that it says to itself "No problem here!"

- If the compiler complains of an unused variable, I comment out the variable;
- If it complains of a signed/unsigned comparison, I change the type;
- If it complains of an unused parameter in a function, I...

...hmmm. If this was C++, I'd simply comment out the parameter name, leaving the type naked:

```
void Fn(int /*param*/) {
} // Fn(param)
```

> Arduino reports:
>     `error: parameter name omitted`

But that isn't legal in C. With some compilers you can use the `__unused` attribute:

```
void Fn(int __unused param) {
} // Fn(param)
```

> Arduino reports:
>     `error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before 'param'`
>     It's interpreting `__unused` as the actual parameter name

or if they're fussy:

```
void Fn(int __attribute__((unused)) param) {
} // Fn(param)
```

> Arduino reports:
>     `warning: unused parameter 'param' [-Wunused-parameter]`
>     That's not the correct `__attribute__`, obviously

So none of the above work in the Arduino environment. Suggestions?

---

I've been programming in C and C++ for over twenty years, and I know that the #1 thing you should always do is ask the compiler to tell you about **everything** it notices. You need a warning-free compile at all times! Otherwise, you spend hours or *days* trying to find a bug - only to discover that the compiler has been warning you about it all along...

Comment: The Arduino core is a mixture of C and C++. The `void f(int) {...}` idiom should work in the C++ files. I agree it's a shame the core generates so many warnings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I typed all that question up for posting, then tried one last thing. It worked!

```
void Fn(__attribute__((unused)) int param) {
} // Fn(param)
```

So, rather than let a good question go to waste: here's the answer!

Now all we need to do is get the maintainers of all the libraries to put these in... and fix the other warnings...

Comment: Another idiom often used in C is `void f(int param) { (void) param; ... }`.

Answer (score 1):

Within the body of a function you can do this to suppress a warning:

```
void do_something(int value) {
  (void) (value);
  . . .
}
```

You can use a macro to do the same thing, for better clarity:

```
#define UNUSED(v) (void) (v)

void do_something(int value) {
  UNUSED(value);
  . . .
}
```

This can be helpful in situations where you have conditional compilation:

```
void do_something(int value) {
  #ifndef USES_PARAM
    UNUSED(value);
  #else
    other_stuff(value);
  #endif
  . . .
}
```

Comment: I know _most_ compilers will do the "right thing" with that, but I've seen some that emit the "load" - and then do nothing with it. The nice thing about "decorating" a variable declaration is that it does two things: it signals the compiler, not the code generation part; and it merely flags a possibility, not a guarantee. If you actually use a variable that is flagged as `unused`, then the compler doesn't complain. So in your final example, you decorate `value` and don't need both sides of the `#if[n]def`